# How to scroll specific no of items in a flatlist in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a flatlist that shows list of items. I want to control its scrolling nature. I want that when the user scroll it only sees the next 5 items. How can i overwrite the on scroll behaviour of flatlist in react native . Is there is any way to handle it . Please suggest it out.

Suppose there is a horizontal flatlist in which i have 1000 items. Initally i show 10 items to the user. Now i want that when the user scrolls in the right direction then i show only the next 10 items to user.After these 10 items are show if user scrolls again then i show next 10 items. In current scenerio i am unable to control the amount of scrolling.

Same condition for scrolling in left direction. When the user scrolls in the left direction is should only see the previous 10 items

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain your question precisely so i just provide info that may help you.

Full docs in: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

You can set initial number of item to show with `initialNumToRender` prop.

flatlist renders the items you pass it with `data` prop so when you change that value the data is there to load when you scroll further, you can fetch 5 number of items each time you reach at its end with `onEndReached` and have a infinite scroll.

or if you want user to do something before you show the next 5 items without just scrolling down, e.g put a button and fetch next 5 items and add to prop `data` each time user presses that.

Comment: Suppose there is a horizontal flatlist in which i have 1000 items. Initally i show 10 items to the user. Now i want that when the user scrolls  in the right direction then i show only the next 10 items to user.After these 10 items are show if user scrolls again then i show next 10 items. In current scenerio i am unable to control the amount of scrolling.

Comment: @rohitgarg fetch 10 data each times, usuallu `limit` and `offset` are sent with request to show back-end which items to return. limit is number of items requested which will be 10 in your case and `offset` is which position of the list you are. for initial you fetched nothing so its 0, then 10, then 20 and so on...